# expo crash on start on build version

Tags: ios, expo

I am building an app with expo, when the app is running on expo I have no issues but when I submit the app to `Apple Store Connect` and run it via `TestFlight` the app instant crash.

Those are my dependencies:

```
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.5",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.0.7",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.0.9",
    "expo": "~36.0.0",
    "expo-in-app-purchases": "^8.0.0",
    "expo-localization": "~8.0.0",
    "i18n-js": "^3.5.1",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.5.0",
    "react-native-phone-input": "^0.2.4",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.4.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "0.6.0",
    "react-native-screens": "2.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native-unimodules": "^0.7.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "sentry-expo": "^2.0.3"
```

I am submitting the build to `Apple Store Connect` running

```
expo build:ios
```

and then

```
expo upload:ios
```

The app is submitted without problems.

I added sentry to have more details on the crash but nothing, it seems to crash before sentry initialization.

If it helps I have some logs

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1b6d96a48 __exceptionPreprocess + 220 (NSException.m:199)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1b6abdfa4 objc_exception_throw + 56 (objc-exception.mm:565)
2   ComAjouveGeoloc                 0x100949a6c 0x100790000 + 1809004
3   ComAjouveGeoloc                 0x100969aac 0x100790000 + 1940140
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x1b6a63184 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:495)
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x1b6a46ea0 _dispatch_async_and_wait_invoke + 92 (queue.c:1536)
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x1b6a63184 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:495)
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x1b6a4634c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$armv81 + 996 (inline_internal.h:2484)
8   CoreFoundation                  0x1b6d145e4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12 (CFRunLoop.c:1749)
9   CoreFoundation                  0x1b6d0f5d8 __CFRunLoopRun + 2004 (CFRunLoop.c:3069)
10  CoreFoundation                  0x1b6d0eadc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464 (CFRunLoop.c:3192)
11  GraphicsServices                0x1c0caf328 GSEventRunModal + 104 (GSEvent.c:2246)
12  UIKitCore                       0x1bae1c63c UIApplicationMain + 1936 (UIApplication.m:4773)
13  ComAjouveGeoloc                 0x1007974d8 0x100790000 + 29912
14  libdyld.dylib                   0x1b6b98360 start + 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was that I was using native modules which was not handled by expo.
In this case you have to eject https://docs.expo.io/expokit/eject/